# MATLAB does not read multiple worksheets in basic mode

Tags: excel, matlab

I am trying to read an xlsx sheet in basic mode on a windows 10 machine without excel installed. I believe I am supposed to use the 'basic' flag to make this happen (MATLAB will default to it anyways). I read the sheets in the excel file using xlsfinfo command and tried to use that to read the 8th sheet,

```
[status,sheets,format] = xlsfinfo(filename)
xlsread(filename,sheets{8},'','basic');
```

but it always gives me an error

```
Error using xlsread (line 247)
Worksheet <8th worksheet name> not found.
```

I can read this worksheet in the non basic mode on a computer with excel installed. What may be the problem?

Comment: Hm, at least to me it looks like you are doing everything right... What is the exact name of your worksheet? Can you try if it works on the computer with Excel but in basic mode?

Comment: The sheet is named something like "On Hub Lifetime". Has 5 colomns with numbers.